# Event does not fired when i create a button programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I was create a button dynamically with event handler. But the event not fired. Please help me to do this. My partial code is here.

```
 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.ID = "btn" + i;
 btn.Text = "Add New";
 Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
 btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
 Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));

  void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     create();
  }
```

I want to access the create() function when i click the button.

Comment: In which page event you are creating the button ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your code, I'm guessing you're not creating the control in the appopriate stage of the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of ASP.NET

what you need is PreInit, as described here:

> Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins.
>     Use this event for the following:
>
> Create or re-create dynamic controls.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding this dynamic button on page load, make sure its under

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
//add button here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

always make your code of creating one time control that will made should be in side `!ispostback` because they are not need to be created again and again

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   //Your code should be their enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> myControls = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
          myControls = new List<string>();
          ViewState["myControls"] = myControls;
     }
}

protected void override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
     base.LoadViewState(savedState);
     myControls = (List<string>)ViewState["myControls"];

     foreach(string controlID in myControls){
          //method to create your buttons goes here.
          createButtons(controlID);
     }
}

public void createButtons(string btnID){
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.ID = btnID;
     btn.Text = "Add New";
     btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
     Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
     Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));
}

void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
     create();
}
```

Give this code a try. When adding controls dynamically in asp.net you have to **recreate the controls in the postback**. The easiest way to do this is using the **viewstate** as I showed above.

Common signs of not doing this correctly are: control **disappears when you click it** or event just **doesn't fire at all**. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Move `btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);` line one level up i.e. before adding to parent And try Routed events.

```
Button btn = new Button();
 btn.ID = "btn" + i;
 btn.Text = "Add New";
btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
 Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
 Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));

  void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     create();
  }
```

Comment: I have modified my answer : try routed events instead of classic event.